# Set up a certificate of completion to be sent as an attachment to each recepient in Docusign signing process

Tags: docusignapi

Please let me know how to set up a certificate of completion to be sent as an attachment via email, to all recipients in the document workflow of a given template.

Comment: You should not create duplicate qs post, I think you only created [50715670](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715670/document-completion-notification-is-not-sent-to-each-recipient-as-expected-when)

Answer (score 1):

To attach Certificate Of Completion, in your DocuSign account, you need to `Go to Admin`, then go to `Signing Settings` link from left hand side Navigation under `Signing and Sending` section. Inside `Signing Settings` page, scroll down to the bottom and select below options to attach document and CoC in an email to the signers. DocuSign will only attach documents to the signers completion email if the attachment is `less than 5 MB`.

[image]